# View.findViewById() returning null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I have this code:

```
private void inflateMenu() {
    if (menu == null) {
        mFanView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fanView);
        final View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.sidemenu, mFanView);
        menu = (MenuView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewMenu);
    }
        menu.setColors(backgroundColor, selectedColor, unselectedColor);
}
```

When debugging, v contains a MenuView whose id equals `R.id.listViewMenu + 1`. Of course this will throw a NPE on menu.setColors.

Why does R.id.listViewMenu contain an ID that doesn't lead to the view with that ID in XML?

I've tried to clean my project but it still stays the same.

EDIT: Posting requested files.

sidemenu.xml

```
<com.ui.library.slidingmenu.MenuView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listViewMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

EDIT: Problem solved.

To anyone coming here because findViewById returns null: Clean the project. If it doesn't work, clean the project again. If it doesn't work, clean ALL your projects. Until it works. If it doesn't work, then ask.

Comment: add the last line into the if condition and if still the error exists there might be problem with the parameters you pass to the setColors method

Comment: Question edited. The problem is caused by R containing a wrong id. However, clean doesn't solve this.

Comment: Do you import the correct R?

Comment: can you post your sidemenu xml file...

Comment: Yes, I'm importing the project R. sidemenu.xml posted in OP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

(In eclipse menu bar) Project > Clean

Explanation: sometimes during building, the R.java class messes up and causes wrong references to id's. Sometimes when I compile, an image suddenly changes because the id associated with it is changed too. This can happen with any resource, Layouts, Id's, etc.

A way to regenerate the R.java class and fix irregularities is by cleaning your project.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Care to attach the layout that is being inflated? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, cleaned all projects 8-9 times and now it works. I feel dumb as hell. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, That happens from time to time. Frustrating, I know.

Comment: This does work. However I am having to clean before every build. Frustrating but as the dev ill put up with it (for now). What worries me is for the user. Will these null issues happen when app is distributed or are they purely an Android Studio issue? Many thanks