# Fragment getView().findViewById(R.id.box1) Returning null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

So here's the problem. I'm coding an app with two EditText views inside a fragment and a button. When the button is clicked, it changes the text of the EditText. In the onViewCreated() method I use this code to get the EditText instance and store it to a variable.

```
EditText box1 = (EditText)(getView.findViewById(R.id.box1));
```

This works fine. However, when I try to access variable box1 when the button is clicked, the EditText has become null and throws a NullPointerException. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Here is the fragment code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

EditText box1, box2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_coder_free,
                container, false);

        //Works here.
        box1 = (EditText)(rootView.findViewById(R.id.box1));
        box2 = (EditText)(rootView.findViewById(R.id.box2));
        //Same thing. Sets the text correctly
        box1.setText("hey look at me!");
        return rootView;
    }

    //Called when the button is clicked.
    public void setBox1Text(String text) {
        //It's null here so it skips to the else
        if(box1 != null) {
            box1.setText(text);
        }
        else {
            //This doesn't work. Throws the exception here.
            box1 = (EditText)(getView().findViewById(R.id.box1));
        }
    }

    public void setBox2Text(String text) {
        if(box2 != null) {
            box2.setText(text);
        }
        else {
            //This doesn't work. Throws the exception here.
            box2 = (EditText)(getView().findViewById(R.id.box2));
        }
    }

    public String getBox1Text() {
        if(box1 == null) {
            return "Nice try.";
        }
        return box1.getText().toString();
    }

    public String getBox2Text() {
        if(box2 == null) {
            return "Nice try.";
        }
        return box2.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the activity which houses the fragment:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    MyFragment myFragment
    EditText box1, box2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_coder);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            myFragment = new MyFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, myFragment.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_app, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void box1Click(View v) { 
        myFragment.setBox2Text("Some text");
    }

    public void box2Click(View v) {
        myFragment.setBox2Text("Some text");
    }

}
```

And here is the XML from the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mycode.MyFragment" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/box1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/box2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/box1"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|none"
    android:focusable="false" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/box2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="box2Click" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/encrypt_button_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/box2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2"
    android:onClick="box1Click" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the relevant xml and the stacktrace

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Here it is.

Comment: @Cybran where is this  `setBox1Text(String text)` called? I mean on which button click and where is the button?

Comment: It's called from the Activity in which the fragment is held. Hold on, let me add that too.

Answer (score 4):

Exemple of use:

```
public class main extends Fragment{

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.core_info_tab, container, false);
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. This answer is a bit sparse - generally you'll want to add some commentary and demonstrate for the asker if at all possible.

Comment: I updated the answer I think it's fair enaugh. I test it and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to execute `setBoxXText(...)` before having created the fragment, `onCreateView` is not yet executed. Be sure that your fragment is loaded before access it's views.

If you check your code, the only way to box1 & box2 to be null is that onCreateView is not yet called, so when you do

```
if(box1 != null) {
            box1.setText(text);
        }
        else {
```

and it goes through the else statement, it's because you didn't initialize the fragment.

You have several ways to fix this, for example you can set this values in the fragment initialization (1) or use a listener to notify when the fragment is loaded (2).

1-

Use a factory to initialize your fragment, fragments in android need empty constructors, so in this way you will use an empty constructor and also ensure yourself that in onCreateView you will have setted the box1 and box2 strings

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{

    //Empty and private constructor
    private YourFragment(){

    }

    private String box1Text;
    private String box2Text;

    public void setBox1Text(String box1Text){
        this.box1Text = box1Text;
    }

    public void setBox2Text(String box2Text){
        this.box2Text = box2Text;
    }

    public static YourFragment YourFragmentFactory(String box1Text, String box2Text){
        YourFragment result = new YourFragment();
        result.setBox1Text(box1Text);
        result.setBox2Text(box2Text);
        return result;
    }   
}
```

and 2:
use a listener to notify your activity when you can start to set the texts:

```
public interface YourFragmentListener{

    public void onViewCreated();
}

private YourFragmentListener listener;

public void setListener(YourFragmentListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if(this.listener != null){
        this.listener.onViewCreated(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Box1 is initialized in the onCreateView() and that works. But it becomes null later for some reason when I try to change the text when the button is clicked.

Comment: a variable that you declare cannot be set to null by the parent class. Your problem is that onCreateView is not executed right after fragment.show(), so you need to be sure that onCreateView has finished to update your UI, you can test this by following my answer (edited) or just adding logs to your methods and checking the order

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the fragment is attached to the activity before calling `setBox1Text(String text)` else the view is not initialized and `getView` returns null.

There is no need to initialize the edittext again.

You can just have

```
public void setBox1Text(String text) {       
        box1.setText(text); // box1 is already initialized in onCreate no need to initialize again
}
```

If you want use `getView` use it in `onActivtiyCreated`

```
 box1 = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.box1));
```

Comment: My problem is that that line of code executes fine in the onViewCreated from the Activity. However, when setBox1Text is called, box1 is null for some reason.

Comment: @Cybran seems fragment is not attached to the activity and getView returns null

Comment: @Cybran  initialize in onCreateView and use it in `setBox1Text(String text)` and make sure you call it when fragment is attached to the activity. check `if(framgent.isAdded())` and then call the method

Comment: @Cybran you can interact with the button when your activity is created and in `Resumed` state. So at that time fragment is attached. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. Look at handling fragment lifecycle. Just initialize it in onCreateview. **Resumed
The fragment is visible in the running activity.**

Answer (score -1):

To use `findViewById` you have to execute it on `Context` (eg. an `Activity`).

Use: `View.getContext().getViewById...`

You can also try [cleaning the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415556/view-findviewbyid-returning-null)

Comment: According to the documentation, there is no such method for Context.

Comment: @Cybran why reinitialize the editext again and where is the method called from? Which button and where is the button?